# Create a tree structure from a javascript object

Tags: recursion, data-structures, tree

I have an object below, I want to convert this object into this structure
https://jsonblob.com/01108516-324a-11ea-85ac-f114c1112c98

How can I convert the structure of this object using javascript without any library

Once it is converted to the above-mentioned schema in jsonblob I have to show a directory structure on UI

```
{
  "folder1": {
    "subfolder1": []
  },
  "folder2": {
    "subfolder1": {
      "subfolder2": [
            "hello.csv",
            "world.csv"
          ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What should your example look like once converted?

Comment: Once it is converted to https://jsonblob.com/01108516-324a-11ea-85ac-f114c1112c98 I have to show a directory structure on UI

Comment: If I were to propose a solution, how would I be able to tell if it were correct?

Comment: What is wrong with a simple [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) here?

Comment: @ScottHunter I believe if your solution takes in the json in the question and outputs https://jsonblob.com/01108516-324a-11ea-85ac-f114c1112c98 it's probably correct

Comment: Can you explain *why* this blob is the correct coversion of this object?

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Are you asking how to write the UI code?